# shell motion script to do task ,wait and then repeat?

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I've installed motion mmal on raspberry pi and its recording video whenever I run startmotion script

```
     #!/bin/sh
     nohup /home/pi/mmal/motion -n -c /home/pi/mmal/motion-mmalcam.conf        1>/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

However, Its making continous video until I stop motion.

I want to make a video of 5 minute after every 1 hour. I tried timeout command

```
     #!/bin/sh
    timeout 5m nohup /home/pi/mmal/motion -n -c /home/pi/mmal/motion-mmalcam.conf        1>/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

How can i run this script after every 1 hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using crond:
Enter: crontab -e

`0 * * * * nohup /home/pi/mmal/motion -n -c /home/pi/mmal/motion-mmalcam.conf        1>/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &`

`5 * * * * pkill -9 motion`

Comment: and if i want to run script for 30 mins after every 15 minutes ?